# Entity Framework 7 и login failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Пытаюсь подружить ef7 и asp.net mvc 6, но при попытке работы с бд возникла следующая ошибка:

> Cannot open database "Posts" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'alexpc\Alexandr'.

в классе DbContext'а юзаю следующий код:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=alexpc;Database=Posts;Integrated security=True;");
}
```

Вроде бы ConnectionString каноничный, не понимаю, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А попробовать законнектиться к бд через SQL Management Studio через Windows Authentication? Коннектится ?

Comment: @null да, коннектится прексрано, даже через tools->connect to database в студии все подключается, а вот entity не хочет дружить.

Comment: Ну скорее всего тогда у вашего пользователя не хватает прав именно на саму бд.

Comment: @null это было первой моей мыслью, но с ef6 все прекрасно работает, потому я уже полностью запутался и не могу понять где же ошибка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема решена, на английской версии стека описал свое решение(ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220230/entity-framework-7-and-login-failed/30260889#30260889) текст решения приведу здесь:

Проблема решена следующим путем: Оказалось, что ошибка "Login failed for user "Username"" возникает, когда перед первым запуском программы не была проведена миграция, ее нужно сделать вручную. Это автоматически работало для подхода "Code First" в EF6, но в EF7 эту фичу убрали. Для выполнения миграции вам нужен DNVM, который вы можете установить используя гайд с этой страницы: https://github.com/aspnet/home Дальше вам нужно открыть командную строку и перейти в директорию с вашим проектом, где лежит ваш "project.json" файл. и использовать следующие команды:

```
dnx . ef migration add
dnx . ef migration apply
```

Если вы все сделали правильно, то папка "Migration" должна появиться в вашей директории проекта. Теперь вы можете запускать проект и наслаждаться отсутствием ошибок!

Comment: Может, вас не затруднит перевести решение? Всё же не все участники хорошо знают английский.

Comment: @VladD да, сейчас переведу!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить Visual Studio в правами администратора, выглядит так, что процесс, из под которого работает IIS-Express не может имперсонироваться в SQL-сервере как текущий пользователь. У меня подобное поведение наблюдается, если запускать SQL Management Studio без прав администатора.

Comment: Попробовал, все та же ошибка.